# Own mySql function which processes json?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

How do we create a mysql function which receives a `json` as an input and returns the same `json` ?

This is basically what i want to happen in the new function...

```
            json_extract(                                                                # Extract the json object by its path
                jsonComponents,
                substring_index(                                                         # Unquote and trim for receiving path to the object instead to its attribute
                    json_unquote(
                        json_search(                                                     # Find the path to an specific json object by a value
                            jsonComponents, 
                            'one', 
                            'com.parallelorigin.code.ecs.components.Identity'
                        )
                    ),
                '.', 1)
            ),
```

I tried it like this, but it gives me an out of sync error or similar. And i have no clue why...

```
DELIMITER //

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS json_extract_object_by_value;
CREATE FUNCTION json_extract_object_by_value(x json) RETURNS json
    BEGIN
        RETURN JSON("10","10")
    END//

DELIMITER ;
```

How exactly do we create a json function in mysql ? How do we pass json und return json from it ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want to return the same JSON, just use `RETURN x;`

Comment: What is `jsonComponents`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my database setup, somehow i always received an out of sync error but it wasnt the functions fault.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS json_extract_object_by_value;
CREATE FUNCTION json_extract_object_by_value(col JSON, val varchar(200)) RETURNS JSON
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
    
        DECLARE extracted_json JSON;
        SET extracted_json = json_extract(                                           # Extract the json object by its path
            col,
            substring_index(                                                         # Unquote and trim for receiving path to the object instead to its attribute
                json_unquote(
                    json_search(                                                     # Find the path to an specific json object by a value
                        col, 
                        'one', 
                        val                                                          # The value we wanna find a path to in the json
                    )
                ),
            '.', 1)
        );
    
        RETURN extracted_json;
    END//

DELIMITER ;
```

This however does its job.